# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string 3

Tags: php, mysqli

I cannot for the life of me see why this is throwing a Catchable fatal error...

```
$rs_contacts = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT CONTACTID, COMPANY, FORENAME, SURNAME, DEAR, POSITION, LASTCHECK, EDITDATE, ACCMAN, LOGO, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, CITY, COUNTY, POSTCODE, COUNTRY, SWITCHBOARD, EMAIL, WEBSITE, COMPTYPE, PRE, OPTOUT, TPS, OPTIN FROM CONTACTS WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') ORDER BY ?");

// bind parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rs_contacts, "sss", $_GET['search'], $_GET['column'], $_GET['order']);

// execute query
mysqli_stmt_execute($rs_contacts);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($rs_contacts);// store result - needed for longtext fields
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($rs_contacts, $CONTACTID, $COMPANY, $FORENAME, $SURNAME, $DEAR, $POSITION, $LASTCHECK, $EDITDATE, $ACCMAN, $LOGO, $ADDRESS1, $ADDRESS2, $ADDRESS3, $CITY, $COUNTY, $POSTCODE, $COUNTRY, $SWITCHBOARD, $EMAIL, $WEBSITE, $COMPTYPE, $PRE, $OPTOUT, $TPS, $OPTIN);// bind result variables
$rowcount_contacts = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($rs_contacts);
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you sure it's on that line? Ideally that should be `$conn->prepare("SELECT ...")` but otherwise nothing looks awry here.

Comment: Not entirely... I'll update the query to include the whole query processing.

Comment: This line shouldn't be capable of generating this type of error. I'd expect that to show up somewhere else when `$rs_contacts` is used.

Comment: Updated the post.  Wondering if it's in the bind results?

Comment: This code would be a lot less cluttered in the OO form, like `$rs_contacts->store_result()` versus that verbose procedural form. In any case, which line pops the error? Another thing to consider is [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of creating a whole heap of variables. You can use `$row['CONTACTID']` instead.

Comment: It says line 51 which relates to the statement itself but I'm using includes so I don't know if that throws the line count out?  What sort of thing would return this error?

Comment: I'm on an old version of MySQL which doesn't support store_result() regrettably.

Comment: I'm publishing the file online at https://www.dropbox.com/s/drgtir4yp7n8hb0/2lookup-detailed.php?dl=0

Comment: Bump - any feedback or am I drawing a blank here?

Comment: There's really not enough here to reproduce. Can you include any relevant source in the question itself, not some random Dropbox link?

Comment: I believe the relevant source is in the question; however, as I said, due to includes and lines of php that don't appear in the final rendered html, I can't be sure which line is responsible.  That's why I included the entire php file as a dropbox link.

Comment: You absolutely can be sure which line is responsible. PHP will tell you which one produced the error in the error logs, so check there for more details.

Comment: The page states line 51 - which is the select statement given above.

Comment: That error shouldn't come from that line. I'd still strongly advise you switch this to the object-oriented form so you can't make mistakes like that. `$conn->prepare(...)` will surface errors far quicker than the procedural approach.

Comment: Thanks @tadman.  As it happens, I think I've found the issue.  There was an unfinished echo statement on an earlier line - hence the confusion over line numbers.  Weirdly, I still can't get the "WHERE ? LIKE..." to work but that's another story for another day.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. If you've got a syntax highlighting editor it can often surface minor syntax problems like that to avoid having to spend hours hunting around for a missing semi-colon. Another trick is to try and keep your lines < *N* characters, where *N* is often 80 and sometimes 132, but enough you can see each line in whole without horizontal scrolling. Past that point you may have errors you can't see.